# How can i hide screen.blit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I made a background music ingame, i put a volume muted & unmuted sprite and made it clickable,
When you mute the music, i want screen.blit(unmute) to disappear.

Source Code:

```
...
x = 0
pygame.mixer.music.load("soundtrack.wav")
volume = pygame.image.load("volume.png")
mute = pygame.image.load("mute.png")
resized_volume = pygame.transform.scale(volume, (100, 100))
resized_mute = pygame.transform.scale(mute, (100,100))
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)


while Loop: # main game loop
...


        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # 1 == left
                vol_rect = volume.get_rect(topleft = (700,500))
                if vol_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    x += 1
                    if x > 2:
                        x = 1
                    if x == 1:
                        screen.blit(mute,(700,500))
                        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                    else:
                        if x == 2:
                            screen.blit(volume, (700,500))
                            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

...

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redraw the scene in every frame. Draw the sprites depending on the value of the variable `x`. e.g.:

```py
while Loop: # main game loop

    # [...]

    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1: # 1 == left
            # [...]

    # [...]

    if x == 0:
        # [...] draw something different
    elif x == 1:
        screen.blit(mute,(700,500))
    elif x == 2:
        screen.blit(volume, (700,500))

    # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try but I hope it works:

```
class MuteUnmute_Button:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 500
        self.y = 400
        self.state = True
        self.mute_image = pygame.image.load("mute_image.png")
        self.unmute_image = pygame.image.load("unmute_image.png")
        self.image = mute_image
        self.screen = screen
    def redraw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
    def checkCollision(self):
        rect = self.image.get_rect()
        return rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.pos)
    def changeImage(self):
        if self.state:
            self.image = self.mute_image
        else:
            self.image = self.unmute_image

mute_unmute_button = MuteUnmuteButton()

while Loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if mute_unmute_button.checkCollision():
                    if mute_unmute_button.state:
                        mute_unmute_button.state = False
                        mute_unmute_button.changeImage()
                        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                    else:
                        mute_unmute_button.state = True
                        mute_unmute_button.changeImage()
                        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    screen.fill((255,255,255)) #Fills background
    mute_unmute_button.redraw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I gave a example, you can change code for your program.